# JAVA Web-App manage JS / CSS dependencies

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, dependency-management

I'm writing an Web-App with Spring boot. So far everything is working well. Over time there is are many third-party Javascrips and CSS (JQuery, Bootstrap etc.) I'm using. At the moment im they are all copied manually in my ressource folder.

Is there an option to manage them via maven? So that they are downloaded an copied during build, so that I dont need to manage the files by myselfe?